# How to get current location and network IP in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When Staff login we need to retrieve the current location automatically and insert it.It's an online punch In/Out system.So just to make sure that In/Out is not misused by punching In/Out in from other places. Using the `http://ipinfo.io/` as Gaurang Joshi mentioned below i get the internet IP and latitude and logitudes.So do i need to use any google map library to get the specific location?How to implement it?Any Help.

Comment: please provide a example and where to save your location??

Comment: Check this may be help you. [http://theonlytutorials.com/user-current-location-ip-address-simple-php-script/]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Server IP**

To get server IP address by `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

**Local IP**

To get client IP by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

---

To find location simply do:

```
//ipinfo grabs the ip of the person requesting

 $getloc = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/"));

 echo $getloc->city; //to get city
```

If you are using coordinates it returns in single string like 32,-72 so, for that you can use:

```
$coordinates = explode(",", $getloc->loc); // -> '32,-72' becomes'32','-72'
echo $coordinates[0]; // latitude
echo $coordinates[1]; // longitude
```

Comment: this returns Internet IP right apart from locatoin,is there any way to get network IP?So that when the user logins from other network we can track it.

Comment: Sir,and also to get the locations do i need to use the google map library?because the above `$getloc->city` just returns Singapore and the exact location not mentioned,so i think i need to try to find the location using the latitude and longitude got.

Comment: what you mean by network address ?? is that MAC address ??

Comment: When i implemented this on local host the IP was different,and from the same system i tested after uploading on the server so the IP showed was the server IP,so doesn't that mean from any other place even if i check I'll be getting the same server IP?

Comment: @GaurangJoshi, I just want to know, Where should I add your above code? inside __construct()? because I have to pass IP address to multiple functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function index(){

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //$location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $location = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'.$ip);
    //you can also use ipinfo.io or any other ip location provider API
    //print_r($location);exit;
    $data_loc = json_decode($location);
    $marker = array();
    $data = array(
                'view_file'=>'index',
                'current_menu'=>'index',
                'site_title' =>'site title',
                'logo'      => 'logo',
                'title'=>'Family Owned Pest Control',
            );
    $Lat = '';
    $Lon = '';
    if(isset($_GET['searchsubmit']))
    {
        $Address = $this->input->get('addr_loc'); 
        $jobtitle = $this->input->get('jobtitle'); 

        $request_url = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$Address."&sensor=true";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

        $status = $xml->status;

        if ($status=="OK") {
            $Lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
            $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
        }
    }

    if(empty($Lat) AND empty($Lon))
    {
        $config['center'] = 'auto';
        $marker['position'] = $data_loc->lat.",". $data_loc->lon ;
        $Lat = $data_loc->lat;
        $Lon = $data_loc->lon;
    }
    else{
        $config['center'] ='auto';
        $marker['position'] = $Lat.",". $Lon ;
    }

    $config['zoom'] = '11';
    $config['places'] = TRUE;
    $config['placesAutocompleteInputID'] = 'myPlaceTextBox';
    $config['placesAutocompleteBoundsMap'] = TRUE; // set results biased towards the maps viewport
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $marker['infowindow_content'] =  $data_loc->city.'<br>'.$data_loc->regionName.'<br>'.$data_loc->country;
    $marker['icon'] = '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    $Lat1 = $Lat+0.05;
    $Lon1 = $Lon+0.05;
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = $Lat1.",". $Lon1;
    $marker['draggable'] = TRUE;
    $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
    $marker['infowindow_content'] =  'dskjfhdsjhfsd' ;
    $marker['icon'] = '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=B|9999FF|000000';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    $Lat2 = $Lat1+0.05;
    $Lon2 = $Lon1+0.05;
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = $Lat2.",". $Lon2;
    $marker['draggable'] = TRUE;
    $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
    $marker['infowindow_content'] =  'dskjfhdsjdsfsdfhfsd' ;
    $marker['icon'] = '//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|9999FF|000000';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);


    $data['content']='content/peta';

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->template->load_index_template($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter libraries like this https://github.com/4riel/Geoip-codeigniter.